# grep assign output of command to a variable with proper escape?

Tags: shell

```
while IFS= read -r number; do
    echo $number
    12_dec="$(grep $number 12_dec_all_sent.txt)"
    11_dec="$(grep $number 11_dec_all_server.txt)"
    echo $12_dec
    echo $11_dec 
done < failed_numbers.txt
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~
```

in this I get grep command not found for both variable 12_dec and 11_dec, how can i properly assign the grep output to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simplified version of your script focusing on :
-expand the grep commands with the value supplied by user
-assign the result to variables

```sh
read -r number;
a=`grep $number 12_dec_all_sent.txt`
b=`grep $number 11_dec_all_server.txt`
echo $a
echo $b
```

will display the lines from the corresponding files containing the value supplied on the command line